# binary subtraction wrong result

Tags: binary-operations

I am trying to compute: 1000001 - 11011
The way I approach this is convert 11011 to 1's complement to 00100 and then add 1, having finally 00101.
However if I do 1000001 + 101 it gives me 1000110, but if i check with an online calculator it says is wrong as the result should be 100110.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1000001 - 0011011 = 1000001 + 1100101 = 0100110$

Note that I extended the second number to seven bits so that the bit count was equal. Only then did I convert it through $1$'s complement

Comment: now I got it!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do subtraction like you learned in grade school
$$  \begin {align}1000001_2&\\ \underline{ -11011_2}&\\100110_2& \end {align}$$ where you borrow from the left whenever needed.